# css/html: vertical div-alignment-Problem (added live-demo)

Tags: html, css, margin, vertical-alignment

I have a problem with aligning some divs in this case:

```
<div id="preamble" style="margin-bottom: 100px;">Preamble</div>
<div id="container" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="content" style="position: relative; margin-top: 50px;">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

(Of course this is only an example that reproduces the behaviour I want to avoid.)

I would have expected the content-div to align from the container-div. Therefore there should be 150px alltogether between "Preamble" and "Content".

However, (at least in Firefox) this is not the case. The container-div is simply ignored and therefore the content-div's margin-top is ignored too, as long as it is not bigger than the margin-top of the preamble-div's margin-bottom.

What can I do? Is there an **additional** css-rule I would have to apply? I would like to keep position: relative aswell as the html-structure.

Thank you!

**[edit2]**

Hope you are still with me ;-)

Sorry for the delay... here's a live-demo. It's so live, I even did a small jquery-script to illustrate the problem - just try out the buttons.
[Live Demo](http://www.sj-wien.at/leopoldstadt/zeug/marcel/slidlabel/stackoverflow/problem.html)

Thank you!

**[edit]**

The way it is:

[image: bad]
<sub>(source: [666kb.com](http://666kb.com/i/bgu50t1yanlgyvc8u.gif))</sub>

The way I want it (without the borders)

[image]
<sub>(source: [666kb.com](http://666kb.com/i/bgu561f1wvb3aejsu.gif))</sub>

I hope the difference is obvious although the images are jerky ;-)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, neither in FF 3.6, IE 8 nor Chrome. There is always a 150px distance between the bottom of preamble and the top of content.

Comment: Can you link to a live demo of your problem? And -obviously- I'd suggest first ensuring you're using/declaring a valid doctype, to avoid quirks-mode bugs.

Comment: strange... I add pictures - and I'll add a live demo when I'm at home and have access to my ftp-servers (in about 1 hour).

Comment: Difference NOT clear ;)!

Answer (score 1):

That's because overlapping vertical margins are collapsed.

[The CSS2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) says:

> In this specification, the expression collapsing margins means that adjoining margins (no non-empty content, padding or border areas or clearance separate them) of two or more boxes (which may be next to one another or nested) combine to form a single margin.

In your case, because `#preamble`'s `margin-bottom` and `#container`'s `margin-top` overlaps, they get collapsed, so the effective margin is the bigger one (in this case, 100px).

If background color is not an issue, you can use `padding` instead of `margin`.

Comment: it would be clear IF #container WOULD HAVE a margin-top. In fact not #container but #content does have a margin-top. Seems like you are right nevertheless, still this fact seems strange to me...

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="preamble" style="margin-bottom: 100px;">Preamble</div> 
<div id="container" style="position: relative;"> 
    <div id="content" style="position: relative; margin-top: 50px;"> 
        Content 
    </div> 
</div>
```

First of all, i recon making a stylesheet. It will save you time when you have alot of elements and also will keep your code cleaner.

What i see when i test your code is that the content div is showing inside of the Container with a margin on the top of 50px. What's wrong?

I think what you want to achiev is this:

```
<div id="preamble" style="margin-bottom: 100px; border: solid black 1px;">Preamble
 <div id="container" style="position: relative; border: solid black 1px;"> 
  <div id="content" style="position: relative; margin-top: 50px; border: solid black 1px;"> 
   Content 
  </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

Good luck! You didn't nest the Div inside the other one and therefore it wouldn't be a total of 150px together ;). Remember Margin is Outside the cell and padding inside the cell!

When i read now that you want to keep your html structure the same, that's not possible.
As soon as you give your first div a margin of 100px this means the next element will be placed 100px under that element. And because you a nested div next with a margin on the top of 50px this means you create more then 150px of total space...

Why did you wanna maintain your html structure?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to keep my html-structure, because I just simplified a far more complex (jquery)-problem with this example. The content-div should move down on certain (mouse)-events by expanding margin-top. Everything else should stay the same. I hope there is a solution... (I didn't downvote)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way out of this miracle: the good old overflow: hidden; trick...

When you add the property overflow: hidden; to #container, the behaviour is just like expected.

You can proove the difference [here](http://www.sj-wien.at/leopoldstadt/zeug/marcel/slidlabel/stackoverflow/solution.html)

Still I'm not completely convinced. Why does this trick solve my problem and are there other ways to do it?

Thanks for your help anyway!